# Why do sites start to throw HTTP 503 error after installing google sitemap generator

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-x64

Why do all the sites on IIS start to throw HTTP 503 error after installing google sitemap generator?

I noticed that app pools are crashing. If I restart an app pool it crashes again after few minutes.
It all started after installing the Google sitemap generator tool (sitemap_win-beta1-20091231.msi).

We did not have the problem on Windows server 2003 32bit OS and IIS6.
The problem exists on IIS 7 running on Windows Server 2008 64bit OS.

Answer (score 3):

The path of the Google SiteMap Generator Module was set incorrectly by the installer on Windows Server 2008 running 64bit OS.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Sitemap Generator\\IIS7_Module_x64.dll
```

Notice the slashes before the name of the dll file.

To correct the issue do the followings:

- Click your server name in the IIS Manager
- Click ‘Modules’
- Select an entry named like ‘GoogleSiteMapGeneratorModule’ and click ‘Edit’
- Replace the double slash with a single slash in the path field
- You might need to reboot the IIS